# Why does my HTML post request not get handled correctly in my Node.js express web app?

Tags: html, node.js, express, post

I have a very simple Node.js web app using the express and body-parser packages but I can't get my HTML post request to be processed with a response from the remote server.

Here is my `index.html` file;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="First Number">
            <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my `calculator.js` Javascript file;

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
   
//    var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
//    var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);

//    var result = num1 + num2;
//    res.send("The result of the calculation is " + result);
    res.send("Thanks for posting that!"); 
});

app.listen();
```

Here is my `package.json` file;

```
{
  "name": "calculator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Learning NodeJS with a calculator app",
  "main": "calculator.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "****",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

When I type in the two numbers and click calculate the browser just appears to re-load `index.html` instead of displaying the message sent from the remote server, `Thanks for posting that!`.

I have tried using a local server connection on my mac and it all works fine.

Comment: You say it doesn't work but then you say it works fine? So does it work or not?

Comment: It works with a local server connection but not a remote server connection.

Comment: What do you mean by *remote server connection*? Did you host your server code somewhere?

Comment: I have hosted my Web app on a Namecheap shared server in my hosting account with Namecheap.

Comment: @IsaacNewtonGravity — Does the hosting package you use actually support Node.js server applications? Are you following instructions for deploying Node.js appliations? Or are you just dumping your Node.js application source code on Namecheap's Apache server?

Comment: Yes, I am creating a Node.js Web Application from my cPanel tools correctly as I have managed to get an even simpler web app to work with a single GET request. It just doesn’t seem to handle POST requests correctly.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing the button type as follows. It will stop the page from reloading

```
<button type='button'>Calculate</button>
```

Comment: The code works fine as it is when I use a local server connection.

Comment: That stops the form from submitting entirely.

Comment: Yes, changing the button type attribute to “button” doesn’t help.